# Solving the Exception. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hub.forms'

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

In my Django web base code, i keep on having this error after

```
from .forms import VisitorForm
```

#### **views.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader

from .models import \*
from .models import Hub
from .forms import VisitorForm



def visitors(request):
form = VisitorForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VisitorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'visitors.php', context)
```

#### forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Hub


class VisitorForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Visitor
    fields = '__all__'
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class Hub(models.Model):
    myname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    emailaddress = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    reply = models.TextField(null=True)
    
    class Meta:
    db_table = "hub"

    def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.myname} {self.phone}"
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('visitors/', views.visitors, name="visitors"), 
]
```

Please what else can I do to solve this exceptions that keeps coming up. . .

```
File "/Users/FOfem/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/FOfem/fchub/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('forra/', include('hub.urls')),
  File "/Users/FOfem/myproject/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/FOfem/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/FOfem/hub/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/FOfem/hub/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .forms import VisitorForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hub.forms'
```

I have try to create a class in the forms.py file with the name "hub", yet the same problems continue.

i did this.

## forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Hub

class VisitorForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = Visitor
fields = '__all__'

class hub(ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = Visitor
fields = \["myname", "emailaddress", "phone", "reply"\]

    class Meta:
        db_table = "hub"
```

Comment: Please share the filetree of your project.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. However, please what is "filetree"? Am new to coding and some terms are still new to me.

Comment: https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/tree1-5.png

Comment: @FrederickOfem: your `hub` indeed does not seem to contain a `forms.py`?

Comment: My `forms.py` is in the *templates* folder that is inside the *hub* folder.